# Google Drive API / SDK, change owner using service account fails

Tags: c#, android, google-drive-api

I try to update the owner permission of some files in google drive using google drive api v2 programmatically.(like Google Admin Console does on "Drive / Transfer Ownership" form)
I created a service account and use its ID combined with a super-admin account to create credentials and "DriveService" object.
I able to list all files shared with me and enumerate the "Owners" collection of "File". Adding a new permission to a file (role="writer") works fine. If I try to change the new permission to role ="owner" I get an INTERNAL ERROR 500.

Had anyone seen that error before and how can I work around?

This is my code:

```
// ---------------------- BUILD CREDENTIALS -------------------------------
Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ServiceAccountCredential m_Creds = new ServiceAccountCredential(
                new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(<MY_SERVICE_ACCOUNT>)
                    {
                        Scopes = new[]
                                     {
                                         DriveService.Scope.Drive,
                                         DriveService.Scope.DriveFile,
                                         DriveService.Scope.DriveAppdata
                                     }
                        ,
                        User = <MY_ADMIN_ACCOUNT>
                    }.FromCertificate(certificate));

// ---------------------- BUILD CLIENTINIT -------------------------------
var myCInit = new BaseClientService.Initializer
            {
                ApplicationName = "Testapplication",
                HttpClientInitializer = m_Creds
            };

string myAccountname = "Test User1"; // accountname to look for
string myNewAccountEmail = "Test.User2@mydomain.com"; // email of new owner account

// ---------------------- DRIVE SERVIVE CREATION -------------------------------
var myDService = new DriveService(myCInit);

// ----------------------- GET THE FILE LIST------------------------------------ 
var myFList = myDService.Files.List().Execute();

         foreach (Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File currF in myFList.Items)
            {

             foreach (Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.User currUser in currF.Owners)
                {
                    if (currUser.DisplayName.StartsWith(myAccountname))
                    {
                        // create new permission for new owner
                        Permission p = new Permission();
                        p.Role = "writer";
                        p.Type = "user";
                        p.Value = myNewAccountEmail;
                        myDService.Permissions.Insert(p, currF.Id).Execute(); // works fine, creates new permission

                        // get permission id 
                        var myNewID = myDService.Permissions.GetIdForEmail(myNewAccountEmail).Execute();

                        // get my newly created permission
                        p = myDService.Permissions.Get(currF.Id, myNewID.Id).Execute();
                        p.Role = "owner";

                        // create update request                            
                        var myUpdR = myDService.Permissions.Update(p, currF.Id,myNewID.Id);
                        myUpdR.TransferOwnership = true; // yes, we want to be an owner

                        myUpdR.Execute();  // this call gets an "internal error 500"
                    }
                }
            }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thx. TL

Answer (score 0):

You can change owner only inside a domain.

Comment: Users in my test are in the same domain. The documents are shared and Admin user can see and change it. Only the change of ownership is ended by "internal error".

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you first of must be in the same domain for the one that is changing the ownership to the other user. This due to a security aspect.

The other one is that changing the file, it has to be pointed to a destination (folder id) and the best way I found out to work, is that the destination-users share a folder to the source-user. And then it is able to procedee with the change permission of the file.

I did it in this sequence to make this possible:

1. Upload file using admin-user and point it to the folderId that destination-users have shared.
2. InsertPermission (fileId, user.email, "user", "owner")
3. RemoveOwnPermission, by sending in the admin-user email and remove it on the file.

Comment: In my case that would probably duplicate the file. All files are uploaded by users and shared with admin. On the end of users livetime the admin should change the ownership to itself to keep the shared files. Otherwise the users Google drive will be deleted. In Google Admin Console is a button for doing that. I try to automate that function without user interaction.

Comment: When sharing the file it is the same fileID, not duplicated in other words.

When removing the "own permission" of the file, the file is removed from the user losing the permission of the file (step 3). Then after that it is only stored at the target admin Google Drive. Meaning it is then safe if the users Google Drive is removed.
The file will be deleted if the user is the owner and not admin when user delete's it's Google drive account. It sounds that you have to automate some stuff yes.